# What is it about tvtropes link disclaimers? is it a running gag or is there some real danger?

Tags: discussion

I have already read many times comments that complain they weren't warned that something is a TVtropes link or, similarly, "duh, dat tvtrope link, damn I'm at work!" or simply sometimes even a simple warning !!ATTENTION!! Tvtrope link: [URL]

So what is bad about it?

Or if it is just a running gag, what's its origin?

Comment: Yes, there *is* a real danger, if you go there, you may never get out.