# Who decides to undelete posts, and for what reason I might be enforced to let bad quality content available with my name as author?

Tags: discussion

I had a question on meta stackexchange about tvtropes, I did my research made sure it isn't a duplicate and asked. Sadly there it was off-topic.

I got referred to this site. So I asked the same question over here.

I just copy pasted the parts and clicked "Post your question".

In the same moment I saw the "Questions that may already have your answer" list refreshing seeing exactly that question in it. I immediately deleted by question and found there an satisfying answer.

In this morning I saw my post on meta: [What is it about tvtropes link disclaimers? is it a running gag or is there some real danger?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9319/44517)

Got undeleted, marked as duplicate (what is absolutely correct), and multiple times downvoted.

So my question here is:

Why I'm enforced to keep low quality posts (I guess the community sees it that way, otherwise no idea why getting downvoted) that are dupes anyway, accessible?
Who profits from this?

Comment: You can request that stackexchange removes your name from the post. (disassociation)

Comment: @CodesInChaos: In generall? Because I requested this on a post of me on money se. and the mod explicitly denied to anonymize the post and after asking on money.meta about why they don't do so, they said they see no reason why this should be done. (While there I was explaining some aspects of my social skill orders, which makes me feel actually really exposed, because they deny my request. So I actually doubt this is possible for an post like the linekd one, aswell.

Comment: IANAL, but my understanding is that the right of disassociation is part of license you grant stackexchange (CC-BY-SA clause 4a).

Comment: @CodesInChaos: So it may not even have been correct on that money.se post from the mod to decline this request? But anyway I'll probably bring that up again over there (as I said it really discomforts me) But overhere I don't care so much about the OP linked post itself. But I'm asking myself why it is wanted to keep low quality content that is duplicated, accesable anyway.

Comment: It's tricky, because the clause only applies to *adaptions* and *collections* and also the stackexchange terms of service might interfere as well. My understanding is that an edited post of yours counts as *adaption*. *Collections* are trickier, but if its on the same page as other posts that counts I'd count that as a *collection*. Perhaps even stackexchange as a whole counts as a *collection*.

Answer (score 13):

In this instance, a moderator (AncientSwordRage♦) undeleted your post as you can see from the post's [timeline](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/9319/timeline). The general rule of thumb is that posts should not be deleted where they serve a useful purpose (signposting) which I suspect is why this post was resurrected (see also - [Is it encouraged to delete your own questions if they have possible duplicates?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7943/is-it-encouraged-to-delete-your-own-questions-if-they-have-possible-duplicates/7944#7944))

If you're very unhappy you can ...

- Flag it for a moderator to reconsider deleting it (using a custom flag to explain what you want)
- Use the "[contact us](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/contact)" dialogue to ask a Community Manager to either delete it entirely or simply disassociate the post from your account.
- Raise the subject on Meta, which you've done.

Comment: Well, actually That one doesn't worry me that much, I was just not seeing any use in it. Thanks for the statement.

Comment: By the way, what you mean by post timeline? or more over: how to access it?

Comment: @Zaibis - I wouldn't fret. Downvotes on Meta simply mean "I don't agree" and don't count against your rep score.

Comment: @Zaibis - In this case, you can access it by clicking the [handy link above](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/9319/timeline). More generally, you can type http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/xxxxxx/timeline (or http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/xxxxxx/timeline on the main site, obviously) where the x's represent the post number of the post (question or answer) you wish to inspect.

Comment: @Zaibis Richard is exactly right on this. For the record,  I don't think your question is low quality at all.